# Listening for key press in lock screen - Electron

Tags: electron

I am building a "Panic Button" app using Electron.js. I am using a menutray where people can choose the type of alarm to trigger, but they can also just press a specific key to trigger an alarm. The problem I have is that once the computer locks, the app does not seem to capture the key presses anymore. Is there a way to still listen to key presses even if the computer is locked? In my app, people should still be able to trigger an alarm, even if all they see is the lock screen.

Thank you.